# Print everything between two patterns, then delete first and last line of the resulting output

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
otherdata
otherdata
start_data
one
two
three
four
end_data
otherdata
otherdata
```

The resulting output should just be:

```
one
two
three
four
```

This looked like a job for `sed` to me:

```
sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/{1d;$d;p}' myfile
```

Did not work. First line was deleted, but not the last line! (for no reason that I could explain by logic so far)

OK, so let's try the ugly way:

```
sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/{/start_data\|end_data/!p}' myfile
```

Fair enough, this works. But I'd like to make the shorter method work as well, as the *resulting* output will *always* contain the two patterns on first and last line, since we're only extracting the data in between.

Why does `sed` choke at the attempt of combining the `1d` and `$d` statements in curly braces?

Comment: Show desired output for that sample input.

Comment: Seriously.  Define "***between***".  Define "***print**, then **delete***".  What do you mean, "... the *resulting* output will *always* contain the two patterns on first and last line ..."?  Do you want `start_data` and `end_data` in your output or don't you?

Comment: @G-Man "Resulting output" refers to the output between the two pattern matches A and B (both of which I want to exclude). And from plain logic, what you get out will always have pattern A as first line and pattern B as the last, so a simple `sed` statement that does a `d` on first and last line will do.

Comment: @Cyrus Oops!! Good catch. Totally forgot to specify my output...

Comment: Thats [`sed` FAQ 4.24](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for that FAQ site, but -- that addresses a different problem, at least telling from the output (*Contents of input.fil - Output of sed script*). It will also print the lines *preceding* first pattern and *following* second pattern. Hence, that's not entirely the same...

Comment: That FAQ is about generally operating on a range exluding the boundaries, in that example they prepend `>>` to each line, but of course, you can use `-n` and print them instead or whatever operation you want to perform on the range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reverse the logic:

```
sed '1,/start_data/d;/end_data/,$d'
```

That assumes `start_data` is not on the first line. To work around that, if you have GNU `sed`, you can make it instead:

```
sed '0,/start_data/d;/end_data/Q'
```

That `0` and `Q` are GNU-specific. `Q` quits `sed` without printing the pattern space, so that would also make it more efficient as it wouldn't keep reading and discarding the rest of the file as with the first solution.

Comment: Though this solution is very elegant, it gives a null string. :(( Have you actually *tested* your line?

Comment: @syntaxerror works fine on your example with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.

Comment: @syntaxerror. It certainly works on the sample you provided. It would only give an empty output if `start_data` was not found in the input or it was only found on the first line (with GNU `sed` you can replace `1` with  `0` to work around that), or if there's `end_data` on the next line after the first one containing `start_data`.

Comment: YES! __This works__. Thank you very much. I do have GNU `sed` here and the `1` must be replaced by `0`. So what you're saying is, for the `1` case, pattern #1 must be preceded by some other data, or `sed` will fail. Of course, these things may happen :) Gladly the `0` variant will also work in *both* cases, just tried with one of my very large lists.

Comment: Congrats, you've just gained a 50 percent clarity boost with the update of your answer. :) Looks near-perfect now, well done. (Those freaking GNU-isms every time, grrrr. :-@)

Answer (score 3):

`awk` seems to be a good fit to this problem:

```
$ awk '/end_data/{f=0;};f{print;};/start_data/{f=1;}' myfile
one
two
three
four
```

The above uses the flag `f` to decide if a line should be printed.  When `start_data`, the flag is set to true (1).  When `end_data` is found, the flag is set to false (0).  When `f` is true, the line is printed.

> Why does sed choke at the attempt of combining the 1d and $d statements in curly braces?

It is not "choking."  It is just that `1d` and `$d` refer to the first and last lines in the file, not the first and last lines in the pattern.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had assumed! That is, when I match between two patterns, that the `1d` and `$d` will refer to the *resulting output* after I "filtered" the data by restricting the content between `start_data` and `end_data`, not the source file as-is.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this works:

```sh
sed -ne/start_data/!d\;:n -e'n;/end_data/q;p;bn' <in
```

It doesn't even attempt to `p`rint until it encounters `/start_pattern/` and from that address on through to the last line, it will replace the current line w/ the `n`ext, `q`uit input entirely if the newline pulled in matches `/end_data/`, or else `p`rint. And that's all.The output is, given your sample data:

```
one
two
three
four
```

It won't recognize a line as an *`end_data`* match if it also matches the first *`start_data`* line which occurs in input.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right, just noticed that by trial-and-error. :)

Comment: Great update, Mike. Good work.

Comment: @syntaxerror - I really couldn't follow what you said before, but I read it right after I woke up, so, in fairness, I don't think I was all there when I did.

Comment: Heh, *never* do that. A cup of coffee always works wonders (at least for me). :P

Comment: Thanks. :) Upvote done now, since you've begged for it. See, you got 20k rep, so my upvote is just like a water drop in a big sea. You can't be serious to *require* my upvote to be happy. ;-) With 20k, you've achieved everything imaginable that can be achieved on this site. I would accept tens of downvotes per week should I ever get to enter this rep zone...I'd just not care anymore.

Comment: @syntaxerror - no, i don't care - you can vote however you want -  i just thought it was *really weird*. that's never happened before. especailly because the comment's a lot harder to write. I was confused, mostly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer to your question already; I'll throw in another way of doing this using Perl.

```
< inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/^(.*\n)*?start_data.*\n((.*\n)*?)end_data(.*\n)*/$2/'
```

- `-0777`: slurps the whole file at once instead of one line at the time
- `-p`: places a `while (<>) {[...]}` loop around the script and prints the processed file
- `-e`: reads the script from the arguments

Perl command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `^`: matches the start of the file
- `(.*\n)*?`: matches any number of any character greedily within the current line and a newline, zero or more times lazily within the current file (i.e. it matches the least times as possible, stopping when the following pattern starts to match)
- `start_data.*\n`: matches a `start_data` string, any number of any character greedily within the current line and a newline
- `((.*\n)*?)`: groups and matches any number of any character greedily within the current line and a newline, zero or more times lazily within the current file (i.e. it matches the least times as possible, stopping when the following pattern starts to match)
- `end_data`: matches an `end_data` string
- `(.*\n)*`: matches any number of any character greedily within the current line and a newline, zero or more times greedily within the current file (i.e. it matches the the most times as possible)
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `$2`: replaces with the second captured group
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers

Comment: +1 because of your great effort in explaining `perl` crypto-lingo to rookies ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here, let me make a trivial, cosmetic modification
to the input file provided in the question:

```
% cat myfile
red
orange
start_data
one
two
three
four
end_data
yellow
green
```

I have simply replaced the `otherdata` lines with distinct other data,
so we can refer to every line in the input file uniquely, by content,
without having to say “the first line”,
since that is apparently subject to misinterpretation,
or “the first `otherdata` line”, which is a little verbose
(and, for all I know, also maybe subject to misinterpretation).

Now, probably the closest thing you're going to find to your first attempt is

```
% sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/p' myfile | sed '1d;$d'
one
two
three
four
```

Your first attempt (`sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/{1d;$d;p}' myfile`) "chokes"
because (as John1024 said) line `1` is the `red` line<sup>*</sup>
and line `$` is the `green` line<sup>**</sup>. 
The `1d;$d;` has no effect because those lines
(along with, in fact, ***all*** of the `otherdata`/colordata lines)
are already excluded by the `/start_data/,/end_data/` range.
__________
<sup>*</sup>  i.e., the first line in the ***entire*** input file,
not just the matched range
<sup>**</sup> i.e., the last line in the ***entire*** input file,
not just the matched range

---

By the way, are you saying that your command produced the following output?

```
one
two
three
four
end_data
```

Because that doesn't make sense, unless `start_data` *was* line 1
(i.e., if `red` and `orange` were absent).

Comment: "because those lines are already excluded by the `/start_data/,/end_data/` range" Nope, in fact they are NOT. `sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/p' myfile` WILL print both `start_data` and `end_data` patterns, each on their own line (first/last). If you don't believe me, try it out. :)

Comment: @syntaxerror: You're not reading what John and I are saying!!!  As long as you do a *single* `sed` command (in contrast to my answer, which does `sed … | sed …`), line `1` is the `red` line and line `$` is line 10 which is the `green` line.  And the `/start_data/,/end_data/` range excludes the color lines (a.k.a. the `otherdata` lines in your question).  If you don't believe me, try `sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/{4d;p}' myfile` (but first, guess what the output will be).

Comment: To begin with, I have no idea why you're always referring to `red` and `green`...is this some allusion to sports which I don't get perhaps? ;) Or to a traffic light? Symbolism is great, but it's always hard to grasp without *explaining* the symbols first... P.S. Nevertheless, the downvote is not from me.

Comment: (0) @syntaxerror: I have edited my answer to clarify the use of the spectrum.  … … … … … … … … …  Also, would somebody care to explain the downvote?   My answer (1) solves the problem, in `sed` (as the OP requested), with a command that, as far as I can tell, works correctly for all reasonable variations of the input data (e.g., `start_data` on the first line or `end_data` on the last) *without* requiring any GNUisms, **and also** (2) takes another crack at answering the (explicit) question, “Why does `sed` choke” on the OP’s first attempt (`sed -n '/start_data/,/end_data/{1d;$d;p}' myfile`)?